# How to have a wrapfigure not always be below section heading

Tags: spacing, sectioning, captions, wrapfigure

I have noticed that wrapfigs always place themselves under a section heading, with quite a bit of white space. This often leads to my wrapfig captions being below the bottom margin and the white space is ugly. How can I have the wrapfigure appear next to the section heading?

```
\section*{Type IV Secretion System}
\begin{wrapfigure}[23]{r}[-10pt]{0.35\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{cagy_figure_mechanism_paper.png}
\caption{The structure of the \textit{H.~pylori} T4SS. Note that the linker between cagY's type 2 repeat domains (shown in light blue) to the B10 domain is not shown~\cite{Backert2011}.}
\label{fig:pylori_t4ss}
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
The C terminal domain of cagY has homology to a core complex member of the \textit{A.~tumefaciens} T4SS, VirB10~~(Figure \ref{fig:virb10_alignment_2bhv}). The T4SS has been widely studied and is ancestral....
```

The document the above code is snipped from looks like this compiled https://i.stack.imgur.com/baGHF.jpg

edit: Ideally figure 3 would be on the previous page, but I was having trouble forcing that to happen as well (even with [H])

Comment: Try to reduce the number `[23]`. It is the number of lines the wrapfigure will occupy.

Comment: Regarding your edit: `wrapfig` does not accept a 'H' specificator for the placement. In fact it is able to read 'r,l,i,o' and uppercase analogues, while the latter ones allow the figure to float - which is a little confusing because for all the other floats 'H' is doing this task.